# Passing Angular form data

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, angular-forms

I'm attempting to pass the data of an angular form to external service, however, the base form is returning a null object and prevents any further processing. Haven't been able to identify the issue. I was able to accomplish an insert form almost identical to this.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

My form

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <form #currentItem="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="updateItem(currentItem.value)" autocomplete="off" novalidate>
      
      <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'error': currentItem.controls.name?.invalid && currentItem.controls.name?.touched}">
        <em *ngIf="currentItem.controls.name?.invalid && (currentItem.controls.name?.touched)">*</em>
        <label for="name">Item name:</label>
        <input [formControl]="name" (ngModel)="currentItem.name" name="name" required id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="name" />
      </div>
  
      <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'error': currentItem.controls.description?.invalid && currentItem.controls.description?.touched}">
          <em *ngIf="currentItem.controls.description?.invalid && (currentItem.controls.description?.touched)">*</em>
          <label for="description">Item Description:</label>
          <input [formControl]="description" (ngModel)="currentItem.description" name="description" required id="description" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="description" />
      </div>
  
      <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'error': currentItem.controls.price?.invalid && currentItem.controls.price?.touched}">
          <em *ngIf="currentItem.controls.price?.invalid && (currentItem.controls.price?.touched)">*</em>
          <label for="price">Item Price:</label>
          <input [formControl]="price" (ngModel)="currentItem.price" name="price" required id="price" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="price" />
      </div>
  
      <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'error': currentItem.controls.inventory?.invalid && currentItem.controls.inventory?.touched}">
          <em *ngIf="currentItem.controls.inventory?.invalid && (currentItem.controls.inventory?.touched)">*</em>
          <label for="inventory">Item Inventory:</label>
          <input [formControl]="inventory" (ngModel)="currentItem.inventory" name="inventory" required id="inventory" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="inventory" />
      </div>
  
      <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'error': currentItem.controls.category?.invalid && currentItem.controls.category?.touched}">
          <em *ngIf="currentItem.controls.category?.invalid && (currentItem.controls.category?.touched)">*</em>
          <label for="category">Item Category:</label>
          <input [formControl]="category" (ngModel)="currentItem.category" name="category" required id="category" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="category" />
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'error': currentItem.controls.image_url?.invalid && currentItem.controls.image_url?.touched}">
        <em *ngIf="currentItem.controls.image_url?.invalid && currentItem.controls.image_url?.touched && currentItem.controls.image_url?.errors.required">*</em>
        <label for="image_url">Image:</label>
        <input [formControl]="image_url" (ngModel)="currentItem.image_url" name="image_url" required pattern=".*\/.*.(png|jpg)" id="image_url" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="preview.png" />
        <em *ngIf="currentItem.controls.image_url?.invalid && currentItem.controls.image_url?.touched  && currentItem.controls.image_url?.errors.pattern">Must be a png or jpg url</em>
        <img [src]="currentItem.controls.image_url.value" *ngIf="currentItem.controls.image_url?.valid" />
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        <button type="button" [disabled]="currentItem.invalid" class="btn btn-default" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router,  Params } from '@angular/router';
import { IItem } from './../../models/index';
import { ItemsService } from './../../services/index';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { JsonPipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-update-item',
  templateUrl: './update-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update-item.component.scss']
})
export class UpdateItemComponent implements OnInit {
  existingObject:any;
  currentItem: IItem;
  isDirty:boolean = true
  // Form Controls
  name = new FormControl('name');
  description = new FormControl('description');
  price = new FormControl('price');
  inventory = new FormControl('inventory');
  category = new FormControl('category');
  image_url = new FormControl('image_url');

  constructor(private itemsService: ItemsService, private route:ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }

  updateItem(formValues) {
    console.log(formValues); // temporary
    console.log(this.currentItem); // temporary
    this.itemsService.updateItem(formValues).subscribe(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/items'])
    });
  }

  cancel() {
    this.router.navigate(['/items'])
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
      this.itemsService.getItem(+params['id']).subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.existingObject = res;
        this.name.setValue(this.existingObject.name);
        this.description.setValue(this.existingObject.description);
        this.price.setValue(this.existingObject.price);
        this.inventory.setValue(this.existingObject.inventory);
        this.category.setValue(this.existingObject.category);
        this.image_url.setValue(this.existingObject.image_url);
      })  
    });
  }

}
```

Service

```
  updateItem(item) {
    let options = { headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})};
    return this.http.post<IItem>(this.server_url + '/backend/items/update.php', item, options);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put all your formcontrols in a formGroup

```js
myFormGroup: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
  name: new FormControl('name'),
  description: new FormControl('description'),
  price: new FormControl('price'),
  inventory: new FormControl('inventory'),
  category: new FormControl('category'),
  image_url: new FormControl('image_url'),
});
```

In order to do so, you need to be able to make a formGroup, thus have the `FormBuilder` dependency injected.

```
constructor(..., private fb: FormBuilder) {}
```

The above code of grouping formcontrols can be done easier like this:

```js
myFormGroup: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
  name: [''],
  description: [''],
  price: [''],
  inventory: ['']),
  category: [''],
  image_url: [''],
});
```

You will need to add the formGroup to your HTML template aswell

```html
<form [formGroup]="myFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="updateItem()" autocomplete="off" novalidate>
   ...
</form>
```

Lastly, you can print the values in your submit function by adding likes this

```
updateItem() {
   if (this.myFormGroup.valid) //Not necessary since you don't use validators
       console.log(this.myFormGroup.value)
}
```

All this information and more can be found on the [Reactive Forms Documentation of Angular](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)